# The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly on HtmlAgilityPack when performing multiple pages request

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am getting **The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly**
while performing multiple pages request for webscraping. I am new to HtmlAgilityPACK please help

```
  if (WebSearchURL.IsValidUrl())
                    {
    
                        
                        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
                        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
    
                        //Home page
                        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument docHome = web.Load(WebSearchURL);
                        HtmlNode[] nodesHome = docHome.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body").ToArray();
    
                        //Contact-us page
                        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument docContactus = web.Load(WebSearchURL + "/contact-us");
                        HtmlNode[] nodesContactus = docContactus.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body")?.ToArray();
                        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument docContact = web.Load(WebSearchURL + "//contact");
                        HtmlNode[] nodesContact = docContact.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body")?.ToArray();
    
    
                        //AboutUs page



                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument docAboutUs = web.Load(WebSearchURL + "/About-us");
                    HtmlNode[] nodesAboutUs = docAboutUs.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body")?.ToArray();
                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument docAbout = web.Load(WebSearchURL + "/About");
                    HtmlNode[] nodesAbout = docAbout.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body")?.ToArray();




                    //listings
                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doclistings = web.Load(WebSearchURL + "/listings");
                    HtmlNode[] nodeslistings = doclistings.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body")?.ToArray();

                    

                    
                    }
```

Comment: Is there a specific start url to use to reproduce this? Does the disconnect fail at the same point each time? Does slowing requests alter this?

Comment: @QHarr it fails when url fails to to match any url ... e.g-www.example.com/contact will be passed if this url have contact page other wise it will throw above error.